# Python: threading.timer not respecting the interval

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

This is a followup to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286049/python-accept-input-while-waiting), to which I now have a solution but the implementation doesn't seem to be behaving properly for unrelated reasons.

I have the following code:

```
import time
import datetime
import threading

def scheduled_function(cycle):
    cycle += 1
    print "Cycle " + str(cycle) + " complete."
    print "Next cycle at " +  (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime("%l:%M%p")

    threading.Timer(300, scheduled_function(cycle)).start() # New cycle every 5 mins
    return

scheduled_function(1)

while(True):
    command = raw_input()
    print command
```

In general this seems to accomplish what I want - allowing the user to enter commands while in the background while a function is periodically called to do some sort of regular activity. However, the interval (300 in this case, which should equate to 5 minutes) does not seem to be doing anything, and the program reaches maximum recursion depth within a second or so. (Max recursion is not a problem for the actual script, as it likely won't be run for more than a few hours at a time).

How am I using threading.Timer wrongly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are calling it right away and not letting the `Timer` call it for you.

```
threading.Timer(300, scheduled_function, args=[cycle,]).start()
```