# do action while raw_input is empty

Tags: python, input

I'd like to do some actions while waiting for a user input:
I was thinking of:

```
var = raw_input("what are you thinking about")
while var == None:
   dosomethingwhilewaiting()
print "input is:", var
```

but raw_input is blocking until a user input come in.
Any ideas?

Comment: The program is not going to execute untill someone provide any kind of data to the "var" variable. It will just wait for user to press enter, so code like this one, will never work as you want it to work.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of this question. Like at least try to read the question, before you mark it like that.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286049/python-accept-input-while-waiting) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576960/python-infinite-while-loop-break-on-user-input) should work. Essentially you need to break up the input task into a separate thread from the "dosomething" task.

Comment: so this is a duplicate of something then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use threads.

```
import thread
import time

var = None
def get_input():
    global var
    var = raw_input("what are you thinking about")

thread.start_new_thread(get_input, ())

i = 0
while var == None:
    i += 0.1
    time.sleep(0.1)
print "input is:", var
print "it took you %d seconds to answer" % i
```