# Python Actions during an input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820909/do-action-while-raw-input-is-empty).

I am trying to do **other actions during an input** for a chat system i'm working on using sockets, but the method in the link doesnt seem work in python 3, with this *slightly* modified code:

```
import thread
import time

waiting = 'waiting'
i = 0

awesomespecialinput = None

def getinput():
    global var
    awesomespecialinput = input("what are you thinking about")

thread.start_new_thread(getinput,())


while awesomespecialinput == None:
    waiting += '.'
    print(waiting)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

print('it took you',i,'seconds to answer')
```

And output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python/inputtest2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import thread
ImportError: No module named 'thread'
```

I have no knowledge about threads, but would like to have some useful foresight on threads, if anything.

**EDIT**

changed code:

```
import threading
import time

waiting = 'waiting'
i = 0

awesomespecialinput = None

def getinput():
    global awesomespecialinput
    awesomespecialinput = input("what are you thinking about")

threading.start_new_thread(getinput,())


while awesomespecialinput == None:
    waiting += '.'
    print(waiting)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

print('it took you',i,'seconds to answer')
```

output:

```
AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'start_new_thread'
```

Comment: Use module `threading` instead (needs different way to start thread) and, by the way, add `awesomespecialinput` to `global` declaration in your `getinput()`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can use [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) with your `getinput` function as `target` parameter:

```
import threading
import time


waiting = 'waiting'
i = 0
awesomespecialinput = None

def getinput():
    global awesomespecialinput
    awesomespecialinput = input("what are you thinking about")

threading.Thread(target=getinput).start()

while awesomespecialinput is None:
    waiting += '.'
    print(waiting)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

print('it took you', i, 'seconds to answer')
```

(The `start_new_thread` method you're trying to use is not available in Python 3's `threading` module as that's a higher-level wrapper around the [`_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html) API.)

Comment: when I run this, it prints

    waiting.what are you thinking about

What I expect for it to print is:

    waiting.
    waiting..
    what are you thinking about
--
    waiting.
    waiting..
    waiting...
    what are you thinking about
--
    waiting.
    waiting..
    waiting...
    waiting....
    what are you thinking about
--
    waiting.
    waiting..
    waiting...
    waiting....
    waiting.....
    what are you thinking about

is this possible? sorry if i'm asking for too much

Comment: @crazicrafter1 Do you mean it prints "waiting" before it asks for input?

Comment: I didn't realize the last comment I made would be so dense, the expected output is supposed to be this: https://imgur.com/a/GtzOZ

Comment: 'waiting.what are you thinking about'

Comment: @crazicrafter1 Are you sure you're not running the thread multiple times?